# redux sagas - block dispatched action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

If action FOO is dispatched and my saga starts a task via takeEvery(FOO),

Is it possible to mutate the action being dispatched so I have START_FOO instead of FOO reaching the reducer?

I know that I can have START_FOO reach the reducer via yield put({ type: START_FOO })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The Redux-Saga middleware always passes a dispatched action to the next middleware in the chain *before* trying to process it, so an action will always reach the reducers first.  You would need some other middleware to modify the action instead.  Redux-Saga effectively only views actions, and doesn't let you modify them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Ignore the FOO action in reducer, but change your state when START_FOO comes.
2. Listen for the FOO action in saga. When it comes you could create a new (modified) payload and dispatch it with START_FOO action.